# How to set file extension in Wicket, FileUploadField?

Tags: java, file-upload, wicket, file-extension

I have a FileUploadField component, and I want to upload only `*.css` or `*.html` files with that. But now, I can upload any type of the files. How could I set the extensions of the files to that component? My code peace:

```
FileUploadField ret = new FileUploadField("uploadField");
ret.setRequired(true);
form.add(fileUploadField);
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had to set it in the html file, not in the java file:

```
<input type="file" wicket:id="uploadField" accept=".csv, .html"/>
```

Answer (score 8):

please note that `accept` is available in modern browsers only ([Documentation](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_accept.asp)) and that you've to check it on server side too.

possible solution:

```
FileUploadField ret = new FileUploadField("uploadField") {
    @Override
    protected void onComponentTag(ComponentTag tag)
    {
        // Default handling for component tag
        super.onComponentTag(tag);

        tag.put("accept", ".css,.html");        
    }

    @Override
    public List<FileUpload> getFileUploads() {
        return filter(super.getFileUploads());
    }

    private List<FileUpload> filter(List<FileUpload> fileUploads) {
        // filter out all files with invalid extension 
    }
};
```

Answer (score 3):

You can create a FileExtensionValidator that extends AbstractValidator and add it to your upload field.

```
public class FileExtensionValidator extends AbstractValidator
{
  private final List<String> allowedFileTypes = Arrays.asList("HTML","CSV");

  public void onValidate(IValidatable _validatable)
  {
    List files = (ArrayList) _validatable.getValue();
    for (Object o : files)
    {
      FileUpload file;
      file = FileUpload.class.cast(o);
      String fileName = file.getClientFileName();
      String fileExt = fileName.substring(fileName.lastIndexOf(".") + 1);
      if (!allowedFileTypes.contains(fileExt.toUpperCase()))
      {
        ValidationError error = new ValidationError();
        error.addMessageKey("UnsupportedExtension");
        error.setVariable("ValidExtensions", allowedFileTypes.toString());
        _validatable.error(error);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use new File()

```
File newFile = new File("yourPath", "yourFilename.css");
newFile.createNewFile();
yourUpload.writeTo(newFile);
```

That's it!

Comment: but I have to use a `FileUploadField` component, to select and upload a file in the interface. So when the fileupload selector comes up, it should accept only `*.css` or/and `*.html`

Comment: Oh, of course. Than you need to add accept=".css , .html" to the <input> field. So it was a misunderstanding.